# Create python nested json from jsons in list

Tags: python, json

I have a list of strings (jsons). `pprint.pprint(jsondump)` gives:

```
[
    '{"Parent\'s Name:": "xx", "School Award Won:": "xx", "Rank:": "862"}',
    '{"Parent\'s Name:": "xx", "School Award Won:": "xx", "Rank:": "872"}',
    '{"Parent\'s Name:": "xx", "School Award Won:": "xx", "Rank:": "333"}'
]
```

I want to covert it to a single json like:

```
{
    {"Parent\'s Name:": "xx", "School Award Won:": "xx", "Rank:": "862"},
    {"Parent\'s Name:": "xx", "School Award Won:": "xx", "Rank:": "872"},
    {"Parent\'s Name:": "xx", "School Award Won:": "xx", "Rank:": "333"}
}
```

I know this isn't valid json, can anyone find out how?

Answer (score 0):

1. json.dumps('[' + ','.join(your_list) +']') 
   Here you create one string, which begins and ends by brackets, like JSON list, and contains all your strings, separated by comma. After creating - dump into python list.
2. [json.dumps(el) for el in your_list] 
   Here you dump every element to python object and transform the result to python list by list comprehensions

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but could you please elaborate?